# Convert complex SQL query to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-to-linq-conversion

Please see my below SQL query and I need to convert it in LINQ, I tried several way but I can not get it working.

This is my SQL query

```
SELECT        SL_Transactions.TransID, SL_Trans_Details.TransDetID AS Expr2, SL_Transactions.PAY, SL_Transactions.Allocated, SL_Debits.INV, SL_Debits.ADR, SL_Debits.RFD
FROM            SL_Trans_Details AS SL_DebitDetails LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         SL_Transactions AS SL_Debits ON SL_DebitDetails.TransID = SL_Debits.TransID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         SL_Trans_Allocation_History ON SL_DebitDetails.TransDetID = SL_Trans_Allocation_History.DebitTransDetID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         SL_Transactions INNER JOIN
                         SL_Trans_Details ON SL_Transactions.TransID = SL_Trans_Details.TransID ON SL_Trans_Allocation_History.CreditTransDetID = SL_Trans_Details.TransDetID
WHERE        (SL_Transactions.PAY = 254)
```

I have tried below way but not solved yet.
C# class

```
public class InvoiceReturnValue
        { 
            public int TransID { get; set; }
            public int? INV { get; set; }
            public int? RFD { get; set; }
        }
```

LINQ Query

```
var Invoiedata = from SL_DebitDetails in Db.SL_Trans_Details
                             join SL_Debits in Db.SL_Transactions on SL_DebitDetails.TransID equals SL_Debits.TransID
                             join SL_Trans_All in Db.SL_Trans_Allocation_History on SL_DebitDetails.TransDetID equals SL_Trans_All.DebitTransDetID
                             join SL_Trans in Db.SL_Transactions on SL_DebitDetails.TransID equals SL_Trans.TransID
                             where SL_Trans.PAY == 250
                             select new InvoiceReturnValue
                             {
                                 TransID= SL_Trans.TransID,
                                 INV= SL_Debits.INV,
                                 RFD= SL_Debits.RFD
                             };
```

Table relation below.
[image]

Comment: Show us your attempt so far.

Comment: @mjwills, I have updated my post with my attempt. Thanks !

Comment: Can you explain `not working`?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, I'm net getting exact result that i wanted. Please see the able structure just added. Thanks !

Comment: why bother? There is no benefit to LINQ over SQL. Just create a Stored procedure and execute that

Comment: What you are doing in LINQ is INNER JOIN. Outer JOINs have different syntax. Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

Comment: @Liam , This is the requirement to do all query through LINQ. Thanks !